# Extending angular yeoman generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I basically want to create a custom yeoman generator that by default extends the standard generator-angular npm package. (by extending I mean giving access to all its sub generators)

Right now what I'm doing is that I have set up all angular sub generators by replicating all the subfolders structure and creating almost-empty js files to just handle the sub generator to the generator-angular package.

I wonder if there is a better way to do it, like specifying sub generator classes somewhere in the code or in a configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Yeoman generator a raw JavaScript prototyped object. Just extend them like you'd do it normally with any other JavaScript object.

```
var util = require('util'); // standard Node.js lib
var BaseGenerator = require('./base/generator');

function AngGenerator() {
    BaseGenerator.apply( this, arguments );
}
util.inherit( AppGenerator, BaseGenerator );
```

You can do the same with the Generator-Angular NPM module, and the same with any sub-generator.

Comment: Hey Simon, thanks for answering! I'm sorry my question was not clear enough. By extending I was referring to a way of exposing all the angular sub generators. Your answer correctly shows how to extend a generator and that's indeed what I've done for now to expose each one of the sub generators.

Comment: Ok, that's not possible as Yeoman explorer the file system to determine sub-generator. So you need to manually replicate the Angular generator and expose the sub-generator manually even if you're not extending them.